# Why gradient of tanh in tensorflow is `grad = dy * (1 - y*y)`

Tags: tensorflow, math, deep-learning, gradient

[tf.raw_ops.TanhGrad](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/raw_ops/TanhGrad) says that `grad = dy * (1 - y*y)`, where `y = tanh(x)`.

But I think since `dy / dx = 1 - y*y`, where `y = tanh(x)`, grad should be `dy / (1 - y*y)`. Where am I wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An expression like `dy / dx` is a [mathematical notation for the derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Notation_for_differentiation), it is not an actual fraction. It is meaningless to move `dy` or `dx` around individually as you would with a numerator and denominator.

Mathematically, it is known that `d(tanh(x))/dx = 1 - (tanh(x))^2`. TensorFlow computes gradients "backwards" (what is called [backpropagation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backpropagation), or more generally [reverse automatic differentiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automatic_differentiation#Reverse_accumulation)). That means that, in general, we will reach the computation of the gradient of `tanh(x)` *after* reaching the step where we compute the gradient of an "outer" function `g(tanh(x))`. `g` represents all the operations that are applied to the output of `tanh` to reach the value for which the gradient is computed. The derivative of this function `g`, according to the [chain rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule), is `d(g(tanh(x)))/dx = d(g(tanh(x))/d(tanh(x)) * d(tanh(x))/dx`. The first factor, `d(g(tanh(x))/d(tanh(x))`, is the reverse accumulated gradient up until `tanh`, that is, the derivate of all those later operations, and is the value of `dy` in the documentation of the function. Therefore, you only need to compute `d(tanh(x))/dx` (which is `(1 - y * y)`, because `y = tanh(x)`) and multiply it by the given `dy`. The resulting value will then be propagated further back to the operation that produced the input `x` to `tanh` in the first place, and it will become the `dy` value in the computation of that gradient, and so on until the gradient sources are reached.