# Tensorflow Custom Gradient in a Custom Layer

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am setting up a custom layer with a custom gradient. The inputs are a single 2-D tensor of shape (?, 2). The outputs are also a single 2-D tensor with shape (?, 2).

I am struggling with understanding how these objects behave. What I've gathered from the documentation is that for a given input, the gradient will have the same shape as the output and that I need to return a list of gradients for each input. I've been assuming that since my inputs look like (?, 2) and my outputs look like (?, 2), then the grad function should return a length-2 list: [input_1_grad, input_2_grad], where both list items are tensors with the shape of the output, (?, 2).

This is not working, which is why I'm hoping someone here could help.

Here is my error (appears to occur at compile time):

> ValueError: Num gradients 3 generated for op name:
> "custom_layer/IdentityN" op: "IdentityN" input:
> "custom_layer_2/concat" input: "custom_layer_1/concat" attr {   key:
> "T"   value {
> list {
> type: DT_FLOAT
> type: DT_FLOAT
> }   } } attr {   key: "_gradient_op_type"   value {
> s: "CustomGradient-28729"   } }  do not match num inputs 2

The other wrinkle is that the input to the custom layer is itself also a custom layer (though without a custom gradient). I will provide the code for both layers, in case it's helpful.

Also, note that the network compiles and runs if I don't try to specify a custom gradient. But, since my functions need help differentiating themselves, I need to manually intervene, so having a working custom gradient is critical.

**First Custom Layer (no custom gradient):**

```
class custom_layer_1(tensorflow.keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self):
        super(custom_layer_1, self).__init__()
    
    def build(self, input_shape):
        self.term_1 = self.add_weight('term_1', trainable=True)
        self.term_2 = self.add_weight('term_2', trainable=True)
    
    def call(self, x):
        self.term_1 = formula in terms of x
        self.term_2 = another formula in terms of x
        
        return tf.concat([self.term_1, self.term_2], axis=1)
```

**Second Custom Layer (with the custom gradient):**

```
class custom_layer_2(tensorflow.keras.layers.Layer):
    ### the inputs
    # x is the concatenation of term_1 and term_2
    def __init__(self):
        super(custom_layer_2, self).__init__()
    
    def build(self, input_shape):
        #self.weight_1 = self.add_weight('weight_1', trainable=True)
        #self.weight_2 = self.add_weight('weight_2', trainable=True)
    
    def call(self, x):
        return custom_function(x)
```

**The Custom Function:**

```
@tf.custom_gradient
def custom_function(x):
    ### the inputs
    # x is a concatenation of term_1 and term_2
    
    weight_1 = function in terms of x
    weight_2 = another function in terms of x
    
    ### the gradient
    def grad(dy):
        # assuming dy has the output shape of (?, 2). could be wrong.
        d_weight_1 = K.reshape(dy[:, 0], shape=(K.shape(x)[0], 1))
        d_weight_1 = K.reshape(dy[:, 1], shape=(K.shape(x)[0], 1))
        
        term_1 = K.reshape(x[:, 0], shape=(K.shape(x)[0], 1))
        term_2 = K.reshape(x[:, 1], shape=(K.shape(x)[0], 1))
        
        d_weight_1_d_term_1 = tf.where(K.equal(term_1, K.zeros_like(term_1)), K.zeros_like(term_1), -term_2 / term_1) * d_weight_1
        d_weight_1_d_term_2 = tf.where(K.equal(term_1, K.zeros_like(term_1)), K.zeros_like(term_1), 1 / term_1) * d_weight_1
        
        d_weight_2_d_term_1 = tf.where(K.equal(term_2, K.zeros_like(term_2)), K.zeros_like(term_1), 2 * term_1 / term_2) * d_weight_2
        d_weight_2_d_term_2 = tf.where(K.equal(term_2, K.zeros_like(term_2)), K.zeros_like(term_1), -K.square(term_1 / term_2)) * d_weight_2
        
        return tf.concat([d_weight_1_d_term_1, d_weight_1_d_term_2], axis=1), tf.concat([d_weight_2_d_term_1, d_weight_2_d_term_2], axis=1)
  
  return tf.concat([weight_1, weight_2], axis=1), grad
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: It would be easier to help you with a whole reproducible example (if your code is very long or complicated just something else for testing). If your `custom_function` has a single input tensor `x`, then your `grad` should also return a single tensor, with the same shape as `x`. You may or may not find my answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62634073/1782792) helpful to understand the value that your `grad` function should return.

Comment: Right, that's the key issue, the shape of the gradient. I will make some example code if need be, but I was hoping to resolve this without it.

Comment: Just to clarify, `x` has shape `(?, 2)`, and `weight_1` and `weight_2` both have shape `(?,)`, then? You seem to create these four vectors `d_weight_*`, all with shape `(?, 1)`, but then return _two_ tensors with shape `(?, 2)`. It should be just one tensor with shape `(?, 2)`. Since I'm not sure what you are trying to do is hard to tell what is the solution, I suppose you need to combine those terms somehow. Also, the values returned by `grad` do not use `dy`, which is most likely wrong.

Comment: Right, that's the key issue, the shape of the gradient. I will make some example code if need be, but I was hoping to resolve this without it. Here's my conundrum: the input is one tensor, and say the columns are labeled i and j. The output is one tensor with columns x and y. I feel like I need 4 different derivatives, one for each input/output combination, e.g. di/dx, di/dy, dj/dx, and dj/dy, since both x and y are functions of both i and j.

Comment: With respect to the dy usage comment, the grad does use dy. It looks like I dropped the multiplication of the dy components when I cleaned up my code for posting. I'll edit the post to true that up - good catch.

Comment: No, you do not need four derivatives, the gradients you are computing is the gradient of the sum of the output with respect to each value in `x`. As in, "how much does the sum of the gradient target (i.e. the loss) change if I change the value of `x[i, j]`". This is computed with `dy` as the summation of "how much does the value of `y[p, q]` change when I change `x[i, j]`" times "the value of `dy[p, q]`", for each pair of `p` and `q` (but usually most of those terms are zero, so generally you don't need to go through every combination of `i`, `j`, `p` and `q`).

Comment: One other thought (and perhaps you were saying this earlier), so if need the gradient to return one 2d tensor, should I just try to combine the underlying derivatives? For example, dy/d_term_1 = reshape(dy[:, 0]) * d_weight_1/d_term_1 + reshape(dy[:, 1]) * d_weight_2/d_term_1. Then do something similar to get dy/d_term_2, and then concat those together for the grad function return value. What do you think?

Comment: Also, my implicit assumption is that the grad function operates at the record level and that automatic differentiation sums them up afterwards. That may or may not be right...

Comment: Yes, if I understand correctly, I think what you are saying is correct. I'm not sure what you mean by "record level", but if you just give the right gradient for your input in your function then the rest of the differentiation process should work fine.

Comment: Thanks, by "record level", I mean one tensor "row" for each record in my dataset. Basically, I'm struggling to understand what these objects look like in the gradient calcuation. For example, when a 2-D dy with 2 columns is the input to the grad function, does dy itself have the shape (batch size, 2)? Or is it already summed, so that it has shape (1,2)? Or does it just have a 1-D length of 2?

Comment: Also, to provide more context in case it's helpful, my network is training dense layers prior my first custom layer. I'm using custom layers 1 and 2 as generalized lambda layers, i.e. they don't have additional trainable weights but instead are just some functional processing of the outputs of the last Dense layer. I've structured it this way, so I can easily recover the custom layer outputs via additional model creations. I need one of these custom layers to have a custom gradient, which I want to propogate back through the network.